# use getStaticProps in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I started a project with next js and typescript. I have a main component that I call it in the index.js page I use the getStaticProps function in the main component getStaticProps returns a prop object and when I log this prop in my main component I received undefined in my console.
I want to know  using the getStaticProps in the component is wrong and I have just to use that function in pages or not.
I am a newbie in next js and I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

this is my main component

```js
import React from 'react';
import {IMain} from "../../../../interfaces/components/IMenu/IMain";

const Main:React.FC<IMain> = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
};


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            data: 'ggwp'
        }
    };
}

export default Main;
```

and this is my index.js page

```js
import Text from "./../components/ui/Text/Text";
import Button from "../components/ui/Button/Button";
import Main from "../components/Menu/Desktop/Main/Main";

const Home = () => {
  return <Main/>;
};




export default Home;
```

Comment: In the example you're using getServerSideProps instead of getStaticProps btw.
Also I tried this code and it worked, I had to refresh page. The hot reloader didn't pick it up immediately.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

getStaticProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.It will not work if you add getStaticProps as a property of the page component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: This answer is correct about getStaticProps not working automatically for individual components (not pages). However, while I was researching this same question, I found this article which describes how this can be accomplished: https://ash.gd/posts/2020-06-20-component-level-static-props-in-next-js

Comment: https://dev.to/akuks/what-is-getstaticprops-in-nextjs-3066#:~:text=The%20getStaticProps%20is%20an%20async,runs%20on%20the%20backend%20server.

Answer (score 2):

Solution

- used react's useEffect() for component
- and for page getStaticProps() of next.js
- after combine the two will have hybrid page

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

Using a node script (like predev) to fetch your content and store it in JSON files in your project, then reference those JSON files in your component.

Posted about it here:
https://dev.to/brewhousedigital/nextjs-getstaticprops-with-components-f25