# Next.js getStaticProps not works in Header

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to get some informations with api in my header. But not works. my codes.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("test")
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.namefake.com`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { data }, 
  }
}
```

I put console.log in function for to test whether the function is runs. but nothing shows up in console. I tried this in _app.js and It worked but I want to use in Header. Im using layout for pages.
layout :

```
import Header from './header'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    
    return(

  <>
    <Header/>
      
    {children}
</>
    );
}
```

_app.js

```
import Layout from './layout'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  <Layout>
   
    
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
    </>
  );

}
export default MyApp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use getStaticProps in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149201/use-getstaticprops-in-component)

Comment: Sorry but which files are page and which ones non-page? My header.js in pages folder

Comment: Page components are component located inside the `pages` folder, that are used for routing. Page components are not imported by other components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

functions like getStaticProps() getServerSideProps()  are server side functions and does not get passed to client side and so it works only in page components (pages/index.js )  and it does not in components  which usually get passed to client bundle

Comment: How would you then pass data to a SEO component to populate metatags for a getStaticProps page ? cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907349/why-my-metadata-is-not-returned-properly-using-nextjs-head-and-getstaticprops ?