# Trying to fetch data to create a menu, getStaticProps is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 & Strapi, and I want to make a `Menu` component using `getStaticProps`.

I created and added a `Layout` component in the `_app.js`.
And a `Menu` component inside the `Layout`.

I tested the code inside `getStaticProps`, and it return the expected json response.

_app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Layout from './components/Layout'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Layout.js

```
import Menu from './Menu'
import Footer from './Footer'

export default function Layout({ children}) {

  return (
    <>
      <Menu />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Menu.js:

```
const Menu = async ({ dataMenu }) => {

  console.log(dataMenu);

  const renderMenuItems = (items) => {
    return items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <Link href={item.attributes.url}>
          <a>{item.attributes.title}</a>
        </Link>
        {item.attributes.children.data.length > 0 && (
          <ul>{renderMenuItems(item.attributes.children.data)}</ul>
        )}
      </li>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>{renderMenuItems(dataMenu)}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const urlParamsObject = {
    nested: "",
    populate: "*",
  }
  const queryString = qs.stringify(urlParamsObject);
  const { data } = await api.get(`/menus/1${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ""}`);
  const dataMenu = data.data;

  return { props: { dataMenu } };
}
```

When I try to `console.log()` the `dataMenu` data I have `undefined`. Can someone tell me why I expect this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getStaticProps` works only for page components inside `pages` folder.
Here is what the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#where-can-i-use-getstaticprops) says:

> `getStaticProps` can only be exported from a **page**. You **cannot** export it from non-page files, `_app`, `_document`, or `_error`.

What you can do that would keep your current structure, with `Menu` called once, and rendered on the server is to fetch the menu data in `_app` using `getInitialProps` and pass it as a prop to `Layout`, then to `Menu`, like below.

_app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import App from "next/app";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, dataMenu }) {
  return (
    <Layout dataMenu={dataMenu}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const urlParamsObject = {
    nested: "",
    populate: "*",
  }
  const queryString = qs.stringify(urlParamsObject);
  const { data } = await api.get(`/menus/1${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ""}`);
  const dataMenu = data.data;
  const pageProps = await App.getInitialProps(context);

  return { ...pageProps, dataMenu: dataMenu};
};
```

Layout.js:

```
import Menu from './Menu'
import Footer from './Footer'

export default function Layout({ children, dataMenu}) {

  return (
    <>
      <Menu dataMenu={dataMenu} />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Menu.js:

```
const Menu = async ({ dataMenu }) => {

  console.log(dataMenu);

  const renderMenuItems = (items) => {
    return items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <Link href={item.attributes.url}>
          <a>{item.attributes.title}</a>
        </Link>
        {item.attributes.children.data.length > 0 && (
          <ul>{renderMenuItems(item.attributes.children.data)}</ul>
        )}
      </li>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>{renderMenuItems(dataMenu)}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

⚠️: make sure you import everything from the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Only pages can export `getStaticProps`, `serverSideProps`, etc. **Not** components.

[See this answer for a workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149362/3530423)

Comment: Thank you but if I want to have a static menu when I build how should I do ? I want to use my endpoint /menus

Comment: Then you would need to do use getStaticProps in the _app, pass to layout, pass to nav, and pass to menu... React-Query, Redux or another state management lib to help instead of passing down all those props.