# Common Dynamic Header in Next JS

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

I have started on Next JS. I am using a common `header.js` component and included it in `_app.js` so that it gets rendered all created pages.

Now I want to make my header dynamic, that is navigation items should be fetched from db and rendered. I tried including `getServerSideProps()` in `_app.js`, but it is not working. What can be done here?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to fetch data to create a menu, getStaticProps is returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143966/trying-to-fetch-data-to-create-a-menu-getstaticprops-is-returning-undefined)

Comment: While the questions are slightly different, the answer might be helpful.

Comment: `_app.js` does not accept a `getServerSideProps` function. You'll have to add your data fetching logic on page level and pass it as props from your page to the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Example:

`pages/xxx.js`

```js
 
import type { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

const Page: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
  return <p>hello world</p>;
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const { resolvedUrl } = context;

  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://api/title?path=${resolvedUrl}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  const { title } = data

  // Pass data to the page
  return { props: { title } };  
}
```

`pages/_app.js`

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Header from '@component/Header';
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { title } = pageProps;
 
  return (
    <Fragment>
     <Header title={title} />
     <Component {...pageProps}  />
    </Fragment>
  ););
}
```