# NextJs best way to call layout and dynamic menu form api

Tags: next.js, contentful

I am new to Next.js. I need to load a certain set of data in the header and footer from Contentful's GraphQL using '@graphql-codegen' to generate a GraphQL SDK. I tried using 'getInitialProps', but the data is not being transferred to the Layout

_app.tsx

```
let siteHeaderData: any;
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const { locale } = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => { siteHeaderData= pageProps }, [])

  console.log('pageProps', Date(), siteHeaderData)
  return (
    <ContentfulLivePreviewProvider
      enableInspectorMode={pageProps.previewActive}
      enableLiveUpdates={pageProps.previewActive}
      locale={locale || 'en-US'}>
      <>
        <main> 
          <Layout siteData={siteHeaderData}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </main>
      </>
    </ContentfulLivePreviewProvider>
  )
}

App.getInitialProps = async ({ locale }: any) => {

  if (siteHeaderData) {
    return { navigationProps: siteHeaderData}
  }
  try {
    const pageData = await client.getSite(locale, false)
    const site = pageData.siteCollection?.items[0];
    if (!site) {
      return { notFound: true, revalidate: revalidateDuration };
    }
    siteHeaderData= site;
    return { revalidate: revalidateDuration, props: { siteHeaderData} };

  } catch {
    return {
      notFound: true,
      revalidate: revalidateDuration,
    };
  }
}
export default App;
```

Layout.tsx

```
interface LayoutPropsInterface {
  children: ReactNode;
  headerData?: any
}

export const Layout = ({ headerData, children }: LayoutPropsInterface) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='main-wrapper wrapper-inner'>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

In my code, the 'headerData' in 'layout.tsx' is consistently showing as 'undefined'. Could you please suggest the best approach for fetching initial data for a website? My primary objective is to retrieve the website header menu from an API. This should be fetched only once and cached for a certain period of time.

Thank you

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76146092/15288641.

Comment: You are trying to mix two different versions of Next.js. Layout files are only supported inside the app directory (available from version 13 upwards). In the app directory neither `_app` nor `getInitialProps` do exist.

Comment: @Fabio Nettis it means I have to call menu data in each page load ?